# Python Принадлежит ли точка квадрату, повёрнутому на 45% относительно оси координат

Tags: python

Не могу решить задачу:

Даны два действительных числа x и y. Проверьте, принадлежит ли точка с координатами(x,y) заштрихованному квадрату (включая его границу). Если точка принадлежит квадрату, выведите слово YES,иначе выведите слово NO. На рисунке сетка проведена с шагом 1.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пишу следующий код:

```
def IsPointInSquere(x, y):
    if x ** 2 + y ** 2 <= 2 ** (1/2):
        return True
    
x = float(input())
y = float(input())
if IsPointInSquere(x, y):
    print("YES")
else:
    print("NO")
```

выдаёт ошибку. Подскажите что конкретно я не учел в функции?
Дописываю:

```
-1 <= x + y <= 1
```

не помогает

Comment: Какую конкретно ошибку выдаёт?

Comment: Зачем тут возведение в квадрат?

Comment: `abs(x)+abs(y) <= 1` Не?

Comment: решил с помощью модуля, спасибо. Ошибку выдавала TEst 15(интерпретатор курсеры)

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант:

```
x, y = float(input()), float(input())

if abs(x) + abs(y) <= 1:
  print("YES")
else:
  print("NO")
```

Comment: `print('YES' if sum(map(abs, map(float, input().split()))) <= 1 else 'NO')`.

Answer (score 0):

В функции не учел то, что это неправильная формула.

Возьмем крайний случай. Точка лежит в координате (1, 0). Тогда она принадлежит квадрату и функция тоже выдаст `True` (1 < 1.4142). Всё правильно.

Теперь сдвинем точку совсем чуток, на координату (1, 0.01). Она уже не лежит в квадрате, но функция все равно выдаст `True`: 1.0001 < 1.4142. Оп, ошибка. И такие ошибки будут в довольном большом диапазоне координат.